# How can i test for an empty queryset in Django?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-queryset

I'm testing a view in Django that should remove all the tags from an object. For that i use this assertion:

```
self.assertEqual(list(Tag.objects.get_for_object(Animal.objects.get(pk=1))),[])
```

That works well, as i get an empty list in return. I wrapped the Django queryset in a list to avoid this:

```
AssertionError: [] != []
```

where an empty Django queryset is compared with an empty list.

But as this is not something i like a lot, i wondered if there is a nicer way to do that test.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just use [`exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists)

```
self.assertFalse(Tag.objects.get_for_object(Animal.objects.get(pk=1)).exists())
```

Answer (score 9):

```
self.assertEqual(Tag.objects.get_for_object(Animal.objects.get(pk=1).count(), 0)
```

You could also use `len()` if you want to enforce the queryset being evaluated as a list!

Alternately also [`assertQuerysetEqual`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase.assertQuerysetEqual) is useful, you could do a comparison with an instance 0f `django.db.models.query.EmptyQuerySet`! But using `count()` should be the fastest way in most cases!

Answer (score 3):

Chris's answer works in this case. But, you can also use:

```
# the_list = list(some_queryset)   # converting a queryset into a list
self.assertEqual(len(the_list), 0)

# to go directly from queryset:
self.assertEqual(some_queryset.count(), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Bernhard pointed, you could use `self.assertQuerysetEquals`, and compare your query set with an empty queryset, although it is an elegant solution, it may not be efficient.

The other solutions are also valid, but here is mine:

```py
self.assertEquals(Tag.objects.get_for_object(Animal.objects.get(pk=1), None)
```

I strongly suggest to don't convert a django queryset in a list. This is because converting a queryset to a list needs to load all the queryset in memory and convert it in a Python object.

For that purpose exist the queryset methods `count()`, `exists()` and etc..