# TypeError while running Django tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

im new at Django or python, but im currently working in a project with both. Right now im trying to get my tests to work. I wrote these simple tests about 3 months ago and im 100% sure they worked back then. Also, when I run the server and try different searches manually I get the expected results, so I know the view is at least correct (I know its horrible and slow, I will work on fixing that). I have searched for this error but the only related thing I found was that Ubuntu was my problem, but I have tried both on Ubuntu and Windows 7. I have no idea what happened between then and now but they give me the following error:

EDIT:I have no idea why all my indentation is being ignored :| oh well, after some suggestions I changed a couple of things and now i get a failure like this:

```
enrique@enrique-XPS-L521X:~/Documents/Reeduq$ 
python manage.py test Search
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
FF
======================================================================
FAIL: test_private_courses_search (Search.tests.SearchTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/enrique/Documents/Reeduq/Search/tests.py", line 18, in test_private_courses_search
  self.assertEqual(response.context['found_entries'],[])
  AssertionError: [] != []
======================================================================
FAIL: test_public_course_search (Search.tests.SearchTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/home/enrique/Documents/Reeduq/Search/tests.py", line 29, in test_public_course_search   
   self.assertEqual(response.context['found_entries'],['<Course: test>'])
   AssertionError: [<Course: test>] != ['<Course: test>']
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.018s

FAILED (failures=2)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I read that this means that i dont have a `__unicode__` function or something like that, but my Course model and User model have one each, so Im not sure what to make of it then

This is the test code:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect, render_to_response, redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from Search.views import search
from Course.models import *
from Reeduq_Home.models import *
class SearchTests(TestCase):    
    def test_private_courses_search(self):
        """     
        a search should not return private courses      
        """     
        new_user=EndUser.objects.create(username="test", first_name="test", last_name="test", email="t@t.com", password="test", account_type="E")         
        Course.objects.create(name="test", instructor=new_user, description="test", tags="test", start_date="2014-3-9", end_date="2014-3-10", public=False)       
        response=self.client.get(reverse('Search:search', args=("test",)))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['found_entries'],[])  

    def test_public_course_search(self):        
        """     
        a search should return public courses       
        """
        new_user=EndUser.objects.create(username="test", first_name="test", last_name="test", email="t@t.com", password="test", account_type="E")
        Course.objects.create(name="test", instructor=new_user, description="test", tags="test, wat, wait", start_date="2014-3-9", end_date="2014-3-10", public=True)
        response=self.client.get(reverse('Search:search', args=("wat",)))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['found_entries'],['<Course: test>'])
```

This is the view code:

```
def search(request, query):
   query=query.replace('_', ' ')    
   found_entries = []    
   objects = Course.objects.all()    
   for p in objects:        
       a=[x.strip() for x in p.tags.split(',')] 
       for i in a:      
           if i == query:           
              if p.public:              
                   found_entries.append(p.id)    
   results = Course.objects.all().filter(pk__in=found_entries)    

    return render_to_response('search.html',
            { 'query': query, 'found_entries': results,},)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just to check, what happens if you temporarily remove `@login_required` decorator and run tests again?

Comment: Can you also assert that `response.status_code == 200`?

Comment: @alecxe omg I cant believe that worked lol, now i get an error tho: AssertionError[]!=[], which is wierd but at least it kinda works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you're getting the unicode comment.
`response.context['found_entries']` is, behind the scenes, doing `response.context.__get__item('found_entries')`, except response.context is None.
As @AlexShkop points out, it sounds like your response isn't what you expect, probably because you're actually getting a 302 redirect (or 401/403).  You could try @alecxe's suggestion, or use the built in client.login capability (after creating a dummy user)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669853/how-can-i-test-for-an-empty-queryset-in-django